# Why Visual Studio doesn't like this XML schema? (Prefix '' cannot be mapped to namespace name reserved for "xml" or "xmlns")

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xsd, xml-namespaces, fb2

FictionBook (also known as FB2) is an XML-based format of electronic books. Its schema can be found here:

http://gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0/xsd/

However, when I downloaded this schema and tried to open it in Visual Studio 2012 I got a bunch of errors, the first of which was: *Prefix '' cannot be mapped to namespace name reserved for "xml" or "xmlns". Line 5, position 118. E:\dev\fb2\FictionBook2.xsd*.

Is the schema really invalid? If so, how is it possible that a lot of software use it to validate FB2 files? Is there an easy way to modify the schema to make VS happy?

Comment: The problem's actually with http://gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0/xsd/FictionBookLang.xsd . You'll see a problem just trying to display it in a browser.

Comment: And FYI I found this by trying to replicate your issue using the .NET Framework classes. `Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader.Create("http://gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0/xsd/FictionBookLang.xsd"),Nothing)` reproduces the error.

Comment: I understand that it's because of FictionBookLang.xsd, but still can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, if I knew that I would have answered rather than just commented :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"` from **FictionBookLang.xsd**, as that is the only culprit:

[image]

The author of the set most likely wanted to ensure that the xml:lang attribute is made available to people. It is not the right way, but nonetheless it could work in certain scenarios.

Typically this is done differently. If your XSD-aware XML processor is "smart", such an import should be done like so, i.e. instead of

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="FictionBookLang.xsd"/>
```

it should be:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
```

This is called a dangling external reference; "smart" XSD processors know how to resolve locations to well known namespaces (for sure, http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace is one of those).

This is what the set would look like, after using the dangling import; the xml.xsd was automatically added by the processor, and it should a copy of the one listed [here](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd).

[image]

In other words, normally FictionBookLand.xsd SHOULD NOT even be part of the compilation. Particularly, if you get these XSDs combined with others that reference the xml:lang attribute correctly, then you will get a duplicate attribute declaration error.

Anyway, if you remove just the attribute as described, all becomes valid; from there, you could build a sample XML - the XSDs are otherwise fine. The sample I've got generated is huge, I am posting just the first couple of lines...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<FictionBook xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:genre="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0/genres" xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0">
    <stylesheet type="type1">stylesheet1</stylesheet>
    <description>
        <title-info>
            <genre match="100">architecture</genre>
            <author>
                <first-name xml:lang="en">first-name1</first-name>
                <middle-name xml:lang="en">middle-name1</middle-name>
                <last-name xml:lang="en">last-name1</last-name>
                <nickname xml:lang="en">nickname1</nickname>
                <home-page>home-page1</home-page>
                <home-page>home-page1</home-page>
                <email>email1</email>
                <email>email1</email>
            </author>
            <book-title xml:lang="en">book-title1</book-title>
            <annotation id="ID1" xml:lang="en">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be with the `targetNamespace=http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"` and `xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"` attributes in the opening tag.  Running `xmllint --schema FictionBook2.xsd --auto` gives the following error:

```
FictionBookLang.xsd:3: namespace error : xml namespace URI cannot be the default namespace
="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

Removing those attributes got rid of these errors, although I wasn't able to fully coerce xmllint into successfully generating a sample XML file.

Comment: Try removing `xmlns="..."` and not `targetNamespace="..."` too.